# Laravel 4.2 execute query without using elequent query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query with sub-query .. and i want to write an explicite SQL request and execute it 
Query :

```
select count(*) as count from 
(
SELECT DISTINCT t.article_id FROM 
`articles` as a left join `tags` as t
on a.`id` = t.`article_id`
where a.`flag` = 1
) as sub
```

i tried this to execute the request without building the query :

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec( $sql );
```

But it always return 0 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sub query with **DB::raw**.
A method DB::raw() (don’t forget to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB) allows you to select whatever you want and basically write raw SQL statements.

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select count(*) as count from 
(
SELECT DISTINCT t.article_id FROM 
`articles` as a left join `tags` as t
on a.`id` = t.`article_id`
where a.`flag` = 1
) as sub"));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with DB::raw('your sql query here')

Answer (score 0):

Using **DB::select** should solve your problem.

```
DB::select('select count(*) as count from 
(
SELECT DISTINCT t.article_id FROM 
`articles` as a left join `tags` as t
on a.`id` = t.`article_id`
where a.`flag` = 1
) as sub');
```