# How to add subqueries in eloquent db of laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am building an api in laravel 5.3 using eloquent if I use `/api/location/event_name/event_status` then I am getting results.

But when I use `/api/location/event_name` or `/api/location/` nothing comes.

How to write the query so that all my link show result?

```
class events_api extends Controller
{
      public function events($location = "",$event_name="",$event_status="")
    {

$events = DB::table('event_table')
            ->join('event_details', 'event_table.event_id', '=', 'event_details.event_id')
            ->join('venue', 'event_details.venue_id', '=', 'venue.venue_id')
            ->where('venue.venue_city','=',$location)
            ->where('event_table.event_name','=','$event_name')
            ->where('event_table.event_status','=','$event_status')
            ->where('event_table.event_post_status','=','publish')
  ->select('event_table.event_title','event_details.event_start_ts','event_details.event_views','venue.venue_name','venue.venue_city','venue.venue_location')
            ->get();

           echo $events;
    }
}``
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983462/laravel-4-2-execute-query-without-using-elequent-query-builder/41994906#41994906

Comment: That worked for me thanks a lot @shafiq

Comment: I am glad my answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to make a subQuery try using `toSql` method:

```
class events_api extends Controller
{
      public function events($location = "",$event_name="",$event_status="")
      {
          $subQuery = DB::table('event_table')
              ->join('event_details', 'event_table.event_id', '=', 'event_details.event_id')
              ->join('venue', 'event_details.venue_id', '=', 'venue.venue_id')
              ->where('venue.venue_city','=',$location)
              ->where('event_table.event_name','=','$event_name')
              ->where('event_table.event_status','=','$event_status')
              ->where('event_table.event_post_status','=','publish')
              ->select('event_table.event_title','event_details.event_start_ts','event_details.event_views','venue.venue_name','venue.venue_city','venue.venue_location');

         DB::table(DB::raw("{$subQuery->toSql()} as main_query"))
             ->mergeBindings($subQuery->getBindings())
         // build your query here
             ->get()
    }
}
```

You'll also need to `mergeBindings` if you use any bindings in subquery

Comment: Don't want to hijack this question, but is there an Eloquent way?